# Retrieve Parameters from RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2012, rdlc

How to retrieve the report parameters from the RDLC local report

```
LocalReport localReport = (LocalReport)e.Report;
ReportParameterInfoCollection ps = new ReportParameterInfoCollection();
ps = localReport.GetParameters();
ReportParameter paramV = new ReportParameter();
```

I want to save a specific parameter with its value in the "paramV"

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drill down reports, I use this code to get the parameters and send it to the next data source :

```
        LocalReport localReport = (LocalReport)e.Report;
        //Get all the parameters passed from the main report to the target report.  
        //OriginalParametersToDrillthrough actually returns a Generic list of   
        //type ReportParameter.  

        IList<ReportParameter> list = localReport.OriginalParametersToDrillthrough;

        DataTable DT = new DataTable();

                string org = null;
                string status = null;

                //Parse through each parameters to fetch the values passed along with them.  
                foreach (ReportParameter param in list)
                {
                    if (param.Name == "org")
                        org = param.Values[0].ToString();
                    else if (param.Name == "status")
                        status = param.Values[0].ToString();
                }

        // Request the datatable from ADO.NET for example or any source that will need the parameters

         var dataSet1 = new DataSets.xx.yy();

          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(org) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
              DT = dataSet1.GetAllData();
          else
              DT = dataSet1.GetDataByOrgStatus(org, status);

        localReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DSName", DT));
        localReport.Refresh();
```